# Trouble with loading phar file

Tags: php, phar

I’m interested in trying cloudconvert with php, but I can’t get it to work. I put the phar file in the same folder as index.php but when I’m running this code I get the error message below.
What’s wrong?

```
<?php
require 'phar://cloudconvert-php.phar/vendor/autoload.php';
use \CloudConvert\Api;
$api = new Api(“my_api_key”);
```

> Warning: require(phar://cloudconvert-php.phar/vendor/autoload.php):
>   failed to open stream: phar error: invalid url or non-existent phar
>   "phar://cloudconvert-php.phar/vendor/autoload.php" in
>   /Library/WebServer/Documents/index.php on line 2
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   'phar://cloudconvert-php.phar/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:')
>   in /Library/WebServer/Documents/index.php on line 2

Answer (score 0):

I'm not into cloudconvert but this is what I read ...

You actually not loading a phar ... You try to load the `autoload.php`...

Assuming `cloudconvert-php.phar/vendor/autoload.php` is your full path

your should do:

```
require('cloudconvert-php.phar/vendor/autoload.php')
```

Comment: Thanks. I get the same message when I try it without the phar:// Ideas?

Comment: Check permission + check if file exist in the given path @SeaBass